# No spring.config.import property has been defined -> After adding spring-cloud-starter-config to the pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka

as I added the spring-cloud-starter-config dependency to my project I'm getting following error:

No spring.config.import property has been defined.
Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.

But I added it in a bootstrap.yml, can be seen here:

```yaml
spring:
cloud:
  config:
    enabled: true
    uri: http://localhost:9296
```

My application.yml looks like this:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9092

spring:
  application:
    name: USER-SERVICE
```

There is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.dailycodebuffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-service</name>
    <description>user-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Also when adding it to the pom.yml intellij said me that project.version would be missing

Answer (score 3):

When setting up bootstrap.yml for my spring-cloud-configuration I had to also provide the following program argument for bootstrap.yml to get picked up:

`--spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true`

Two other helpful properties to put in your bootstrap.yml file to control what can sources override properties:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      allowOverride: ~
      overrideNone: ~
```

[Spring cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below dependency to your pom.xml to indicate the bootstrap setup

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```